# Does this probability inequality have a name?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real-valued random variables, and let $k$ be a real number. Then $$Pr[X>k] \geq Pr[Y>k] - Pr[X \neq Y].$$
Does this inequality have a name, or is there a common reference for it?

Comment: It is true.  I doubt it has a name.  Note that it is useless when $P[X \neq Y]=1$, which occurs when the joint CDF for $(X,Y)$  is continuous. It is only potentially useful if $P[X\neq Y]<1$.

Comment: Somehow its structure reminds me of "Fano's inequality" from information theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano's_inequality

Answer (score 0):

It’s probably too straightforward to merit a name: if $Y(\omega) > k$, then either $X(\omega) \neq Y(\omega)$ or $X(\omega) = Y(\omega) > k$. Hence,  $[Y > k] \subset [X \neq Y] \cup [X > k]$, so $P(Y>k) \leq P(X>k)+P(X \neq Y)$. I wonder how much this inequality can be of use, since it is basically decomposing $A = (A\cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)$.